# Pocket door that doesn't require much overhead space

Tags: door-frame, pocket-door

We are installing a door between a bedroom and a bonus room (which used to be a patio). The opening used to be an exterior doorway in a concrete block house. The opening is 80.5, and we would like to put a pocket door here; however, because it is concrete, we can not get any extra height. All pocket doors I have found require 4.5" beyond the height of the door (which would mean we would end up with a 76" opening). Are there any options for pocket doors that don't require so much space on top? We have plenty of depth to work with because the wall is thick.

Answer (score 1):

Go to a real door supplier and see what they can offer.

You'll be removing any top framing from the pocket door kit and bolting the track directly to your opening (which will take a little bit of thinking, but that's the fun of this kind of project, right?), so that'll change the height. Even if it didn't, a 76" door isn't that terrible. (It's only a touch lower than typical.)

Comment: I've seen old ones that run on bottom rollers, but I don't know how common those are now.

Answer (score 0):

Would you be okay with a sliding barn door instead of a pocket door? I think it would be a good solution to your problem. You'll have a lot more flexibility with the rough opening dimensions.

[image: barn door example]